# Как импортировать библиотеку twoway-view?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Есть такая библиотека `twoway-view` которая позволяет создать кастомный recycler view как мне нужно

https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view

Вот только не пойму как правильно ее импортировать

Согласно описанию нужно сделать вот так

```
compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:twowayview:0.1.4'
```

Но сразу есть проблемы когда делаешь ставишь этот кастомный `recycler view` в разметку

```
<org.lucasr.twowayview.widget.TwoWayView
  android:id="@+id/rvMain"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  app:twowayview_layoutManager="StaggeredGridLayoutManager"
  app:twowayview_numColumns="2"
  app:twowayview_numRows="2"
  />
```

Пространство имен определено, но там нет имен свойств так что пришлось руками найти все attrs.xml в репозитории этой библиотеки и добавить их к себе(как по мне очень не удобно как для lib у которой 4500 звезд рейтинга)

Ну ок, потом я начал работать с адаптером и создал свой на основе из примера, но мой проект не видит импорты

```
import com.fittingroom.newtimezone.view.activityMainNew.recyclerViewUtil.twowayview.TwoWayLayoutManager;
import org.lucasr.twowayview.TwoWayLayoutManager;
import org.lucasr.twowayview.widget.SpannableGridLayoutManager;
import org.lucasr.twowayview.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager;
import org.lucasr.twowayview.widget.TwoWayView;
```

я не знаю, что такое snapshot (в гугле написано, что это снимок состояния проекта) , но что это значит в описании к этой lib не пойму, но попробовал импортировать это в свой проект

```
repositories {
maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"     }
}

dependencies {
 compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:core:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT@aar'
 compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:layouts:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT@aar'
}
```

и тогда мне проект показал , что я пытаюсь импортировать эту lib более одного раза

В общем не пойму как это должно работать? Кто работал с этой lib подскажите в чем секрет?

Или может посоветуете другой подход? Мне вообще нужно сделать вот такой recycler view

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

CardView я уже сделал мне нужно теперь разобраться как сделать вот такой шаблон как на картинке для моего recycler view

Comment: А если просто вот так попробовать? `compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:twowayview:0.1.4'`

Comment: снэпшот это промежуточные (тестовые) сборки, за их работоспособность никто не ручается. В инструкции есть два варианта подключения: снэпшот из отдельного мавен-репозитория или стабильная версия из jCenter. Выбрать нужно только один из вариантов.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб так я же об этом и писал в вопросе) что если просто добавить зависимость то, не видит импортов в адаптере... Вот попробуйте добавить зависимость в пустой проект и скопировать адаптер из примера и поставить в свой проект

Comment: @pavlofff да но когда я выбыраю вариант стабильной версии  то, не видит импортов в адаптере... Вот попробуйте добавить зависимость в пустой проект и скопировать адаптер из примера и поставить в свой проект

Comment: Попробуйте версию `0.1.3` - в релизах она самая последняя

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Я только, что попробовал сделать все это с помощью https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Вроде как `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` то, что нужно, но вот не пойму как сделать, чтоб первая ячейка была на 2 рада в ширину, а уже остальные по 2 ячейки в ряду... Не знаете как сделать так?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, ничего кроме хака увеличения ширины первого и обнуления ширины второго элемента с ходу предложить не могу

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Да, но StaggeredGridLayoutManager делит Recycler VIew пополам по вертикали... Я не могу залазить на вторую половину

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, нет ничего такого что не смог бы сделать отрицательный margin))) Но это плохое решение и оно чревато(

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Я думал может закрепить верхний элемент вместе с recycler view контейнере и сделать его проворачивающимся как это делают с toolbar... Когда начинаешь скролить он уходит вверх... Как думаете?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, мне сложно сказать. Я не знаю всех тонкостей задачи и на какие компромисы можно пойти для её решения)

Answer (score 0):

В итоге вся магия вот в этих строчках

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) viewHolder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);
```

Вот так выглядит мой адаптер

```
public class AdapterRecViewMain
    extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private List<BaseMarkerElement> mainCardList;
private final int HEADER_VIEW = 0;
private final int FOOTER_VIEW = 1;

public AdapterRecViewMain() {
}

public void setData(List<BaseMarkerElement> mainCardList) {
    this.mainCardList = mainCardList;
}

@Override public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        return HEADER_VIEW;
    }
    return FOOTER_VIEW;
}

@Override public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int type) {
    if (type == FOOTER_VIEW) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_main_activity, viewGroup, false);
        return new MainCardViewHolder(v);
    } else {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.header_view_main_activity, viewGroup, false);
        return new HeaderViewHolder(v);
    }
}

@Override public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int positionItem) {
    final int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

    if (viewHolder instanceof HeaderViewHolder) {
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) viewHolder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);

        BaseMarkerElement item = mainCardList.get(position);
        if (item instanceof HeaderView) {
            HeaderView header = (HeaderView) mainCardList.get(position);
            // need to add implementation
        }
    } else if (viewHolder instanceof MainCardViewHolder) {
        MainCardViewHolder currentView = (MainCardViewHolder) viewHolder;
        CardMainActivity currentCard = (CardMainActivity) mainCardList.get(position);

        currentView.ivMainCard.setImageResource(currentCard.getIvMainCard());
        currentView.tvBrandName.setText(currentCard.getTvBrandName());
        currentView.tvPrice.setText(currentCard.getTvPrice());
        currentView.tvType.setText(currentCard.getTvType());
    }
}

@Override public int getItemCount() {
    return mainCardList.size();
}

private class MainCardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView ivMainCard;
    TextView tvBrandName;
    TextView tvType;
    TextView tvPrice;

    MainCardViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        ivMainCard = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewMainCard);
        tvBrandName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvBrandName);
        tvType = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvType);
        tvPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
    }
}

private class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public HeaderViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

    }
}
}
```

результат получается такой как на картинке у меня в вопросе